# Bug in iOS 13 Location Authorization Flow?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ios13

I am experiencing unexpected behavior in the iOS location authorization process. Here are my steps including a screen-grab

- I request "Always" authorization on iOS 13.
- I only grant the app the "Allow Once" authorization, which grants the user a temporary "When In Use" authorization.
- I request "Always" authorization again.
- This time, no authorization prompt is shown and the `didChangeAuthorization` delegate method gives `.authorizedAlways`
- However, when I look at the authorization status in the Settings app, it says "Ask Next Time", which corresponds to an authorization status of `.notDetermined`.

**My questions**:

1. Why is there no second prompt when I request "Always" authorization a second time?
2. Why does the delegate method give the `.authorizedAlways` status without me actually giving that authorization?
3. Why does the Settings app indicate that the authorization status is `.notDetermined` when the delegate method said it was `.authorizedAlways`.

I feel like this is a bug in iOS, but I might also just be misunderstanding the way the authorization flows should work. What do you think?

I haven't been able to test this on a real device with iOS13, so I don't know if it's maybe just a problem in the simulator?

[image]

Comment: This [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/705/) explains it well.

Comment: @Don I've watched the video and know about the changes in iOS 13 with temporary and provisional authorizations. I don't see how the video explains any of the three questions I've asked?

Comment: The video seems to address precisely these questions quite specifically. E.g. “So, your app asked for always authorization, and then the user granted it when in use. Now, if the user goes to settings, they'll see that your app has when in use authorization. But, Core Location has called your delegate back and told that it received always authorization.” Doesn't that answer questions 2 and 3 very specifically? And it talks about the second “always” prompt not showing up until an “event” that requires always permissions takes place (such as geofence or whatever), answering question 1.

Comment: FYI, you might want to be specific about which version of iOS 13 you are talking about, as they tweaked the state change logic in 13.4.

Answer (score 3):

1. The user has already been asked for a location permission in this session; they selected "allow once".  If iOS prompted them a second time it would be annoying and confusing.
2. Your app is upgraded to "provisional always" state after the second request; it is allowed to think that it has always so that any permission checking logic you may have built won't keep asking the user to go to settings or whatever. Since the app doesn't really have always there is no impact to user privacy, so there is no harm in reporting "always"
3. The settings app reflects the user's actual choice which is "ask me again next time".

The [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/705/) that @Don suggested in the comments explains about provisional always permission and its purpose in satisfying app permissions logic.

Comment: Interesting. I must have misunderstood the purpose of provisional Always then. I thought it was only granted after requesting Always and receiving When in Use so that it could later either be upgraded to permanent Always or stay on permanent When in Use. I didn't know it would also be granted when calling requestAlwaysAuthorization() again after having the user select "Allow Once"

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Why is there no second prompt when I request "Always" authorization a second time?

In iOS 13.0, just requesting “always” permission a second time does not qualify as the “event” to trigger the prompt to the user. You actually have to to perform the action that requires “always”.

For example, I request always, and got the “when in use” prompt. I turned on significant change service, but did not receive prompt for always. Only when I hopped in my car and started to drive away did the significant change actually trigger the “always” prompt.

---

In WWDC 2020 video [What's new in location](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10660/), they describe a change introduced in iOS 13.4. You can ask for “when in use” and assuming the user granted it, you can ask for “always” and get the second alert (this time asking if the user would like to upgrade to “always” or not). You just need both “Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description” and the “Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description” usage strings.

Comment: According to @Paulw11 's answer I received a provisional Always authorization after calling `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` a second time after the user chose Allow Once. It was my understanding that the provisional Always would only be granted after requesting Always and being given While Using the App by the User.
I guess I was expecting CoreLocation to just ignore the second `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` call rather than upgrade it to provisional Always

Comment: Interestingly I have found that requesting "when in use" followed by "always" a short time later will also trigger the "always" permission request dialog (as long as "when in use" was granted initially)

Comment: @Rob. I understand that the deferred Always prompt only appears after generating events that _actually_ require Always authorization. 
What I'm actually confused about is the upgrading to provisional Always upon calling `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` a second time. I guess I do understand why CoreLocation does not show the same When In Use prompt again, since the User had already seen it, what I don't understand (and also don't think I've seen anywhere in the video or docs) is the upgrading to provisional Always by calling `requestAlwaysAuthorization` twice

Comment: The video discussed above is explicit that one should just do whatever requires always permission and that will trigger the alert when appropriate. That works for me, as well. This “request ‘Always’ twice” is not what they recommend in that video, and as such, I wouldn’t rely on that pattern.

Comment: Yes I know. I just accidentally came across that when I was tapping around in the app and wondered why it behaved that way. I wasn't able to explain the behavior based on what I had learned from the video and thought I'd ask here. 
I do understand that when I actually want permanent Always authorization the path is Request Always -> User selects When In Use -> App does what requires Always permission -> CoreLocation shows second prompt when events come in.

Comment: @Rob The weird part is that Apple claims that in iOS 14 this behavior has changed: if you request Always authorization when you already have When In Use authorization, the dialog appears _now_ offering to promote Always. But I can't get that to happen; to me it seems like nothing has changed at all.

Comment: @matt - That new flow was introduced in iOS 13.4, not in iOS 14, and it works as they describe, at least for me (namely ask once for when in use and get system alert; ask again for always and get second system permissions alert immediately). I don't get that second alert in 13.0 (I have to actually use whatever required “always” service), but I do in 13.4 and later. As long as you have both “Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description” and the “Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description” usage strings, it should work fine.

Comment: Can’t get the second alert to appear in iOS 14 beta 4. Simple test, I just ask for When In Use, see the alert, grant it, ask for Always, I see no second alert.

Comment: Well, this morning it's working. I can't imagine what the issue was, sorry about that. I assure you I spent all day yesterday testing this and couldn't get it to work as advertised...!

Comment: OK, so _now_ the problem is in the _other_ situation. I ask for Always authorization when we are `notDetermined`, and I get it even though the user thinks it is When In Use Authorization. This is supposed to be "provisional". But I didn't do any location monitoring, and yet the authorization my app see never reverts to When In Use. It stays at Always. This whole flow is so crazy, it's hard to justify and harder to test.

Comment: While app is in that “provisional always” state, the `authorizationStatus` will report “always” until the provisional status is resolved. Only if you do something in the app that requires “always”, triggering the second alert, and the user denies “always”, only then should it “revert” to “when in use”. This is by design. I understand why Apple did it this way, but, IMHO, but this solution of having a status for the programmer that isn’t the actual status shown to the user is a mind-numbingly stupid design.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea. Here's my question on this topic; you might like to give that as an answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430371/what-makes-provisional-always-authorization-provisional So the reason why we never revert _is_ that we never use our Always powers. I assumed it was "use it or lose it", but in fact you're saying it's "you don't lose it _until_ you use it". My test is flawed, and you should tell me so. :)