# iBeacon ranging stops "seeing" beacons when screen is off but only on some devices

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

The app I'm working on monitors beacons in the background, when one is detected we start ranging beacons.

This worked, until we tested on a few more devices and found that on some devices turning off the screen would still invoke `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion)` but `beacons` would be empty. As soon as the screen is turned on (a notification arrives, raise to wake, tap to wake, etc.) the ranging starts working correctly until the screen turns off again.

When creating a test project to reproduce the issue, I noticed that the ranging works on these devices while the screen is off if monitoring is stopped. While this is *a* solution, it's not *the* solution since it causes issues later down the road.

**Does anyone know what is different between these devices? Is this a hardware issue, some OS setting?**

Answer (score 1):

After some more testing I discovered that this is not an issue if you monitor the same beacon you are trying to range.

To summarise, while the screen is off (with necessary capabilities):

- Ranging (beacon #1) ✅
- Ranging (beacon #1) and monitoring (beacon #2) ❌
- Ranging (beacon #1) and monitoring (beacon #1 and #2) ✅

On some level this makes sense, as monitoring is done by the system vs ranging which is done by the app, and these processes interact somehow.

The question remains why is this behaviour different across devices. My current theory is that it might be linked to battery health, so the BT chip might get throttled in some way, as most devices this failed to work on had battery health < 90%.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your location permissions on each device by going to Settings -> Apps -> Your App -> Permissions -> Location.  Make sure all of them have "Always" location access.

If you have "when in use" permission granted, then the ranging will stop if the app is not in the foreground.  The screen being off counts as not being in the foreground.  To complicate things further, there is also a "provisional" always location permission as of iOS 13+ which will act like you have granted always when the settings screen shows "when in use".  You can read more about that here:  [What makes provisional Always authorization provisional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430371/what-makes-provisional-always-authorization-provisional)

It is also possible you have discovered some kind of bug -- monitoring for a second region shouldn't affect ranging the first region.   But I can imaging incorrectly coding an optimization module that shuts down frequent beacon scanning if no beacons associated with a monitored region are visible -- e.g. in the case where all your monitored regions are in the "outside" state.   I can also imagine there may some relationship between this poorly coded optimization and the specific location permission grant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer David, I'm aware of the issues you are talking about. For this reason we skip showing the location permission popup and ask the user to set location permission to "always" directly in the system settings. In my tests all the phones were set to "always" and I tested with 10 different phones, so that was not the issue. I think your guess about poor optimisation might be right.

Comment: While inelegant, you might consider simply always monitoring any region you range.  (Or if you use case allows, simply not using monitoring at all)

Comment: Yes, that is the workaround for now. We monitor the regions we are ranging.